# Error 404 : The requested page do not exist

Tags: magento2, routing

My target URL is: `http://mylocalhost/devis/customer/printPdf`

But it triggers a 404 and I can't find why

I have my frontend router

`app/code/FT/Devis/etc/frontend/routex.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="devis" frontName="devis">
            <module name="FT_Devis" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

And I have my Controller

`app/code/FT/Devis/Controller/Customer/PrintPdf.php`

And of course, this class extends the action to have his own construct and execute method.

Can't figure out why this routes is not working.
Moreover, it was something who worked before I think.

Comment: routex.xml is an incorrect file name (or is it a typo?)

Comment: typo, issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create routes.xml file.
File: app/code/Vendor/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="helloworld" id="helloworld">
            <module name="Vendor_HelloWorld"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Step 2: Create controller file
File: app/code/Vendor/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo'magentocontroller'; exit;
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Browse  `http://<yourhost.com>/helloworld/index/index`

Comment: Actually I've been a little too fast on conclusion, I was hitting my controller but a redirection was hidden in the controller. So it wasn't a real 404 but a redirect from the controller to a 404.

Issue is fixed.